# "df -h" unable to show the command output on a Linux System

Tags: disk-usage

I was trying to check the amount of hard drive by typing *df -h*

Its showing me below status since long time.

```
  svn_manager@fileserver:~$ df -h
  ^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^Z^Z^Z^X^X^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

I have 1 network shared folder mounted and 1 usb drive attached but both the shared function working from other pc.

I tried to kill by using Crtl+c | Crtl+z | Crtl+d but no success.

Closing the terminal work but when i reopen the terminal and run it again its having same issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. For example, do you have any network mounted drives? Could `df` be trying to access a filesystem that was mounted from a remote server but that server is now not accessible? We can't help unless you give us more detail.

Comment: Do you have any network device mounted in your system. If yes, then might be the issue that your network devices are not responding. use df -lh to see if that works.

Comment: Yes i have mounted a network shared folder and a usb drive attached. the  both shared network folder and usb drive also (shared) for network working properly.

Comment: [Don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda I will take care for the next time, but was not possible to describe the issue clearly without posting image its output of command.

Comment: @terdon I have edited the question and described more .

Comment: When I'm not certain what a process is doing, if I can't find logs or any other data, I use `strace`. In another terminal, use `ps aux` or `ps axjf` to find the PID. Once you have that, run `strace -fp <PID>`. This should let you know  what system calls it is running in real time. File read/write and network connections should be recorded there. My guess is that it' a problem or latency reading from the network or from a certain device.

Comment: I have load average: 88.00, 87.75, 87.14 %CPU = 1.3 %MEM=10% is it the issue causing df -h status?

Comment: You said the shared network folder is working properly. If you cd to a directory in that folder and run `ls -l`, does that work OK?

Comment: try it just for the local partition you are interested in e.g.`df -h /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2`

Comment: Yes its working and showing me the exact data and folder structure..

Comment: `dmesg` output maybe helpful, as well as examining process tree.

Comment: The status of Dmesg here. _4392840.164351]  [<f863f6b7>] cifs_getattr+0x47/0x110 [cifs]_
_[4392840.164366]  [<f863f670>] ? cifs_revalidate_dentry+0x30/0x30_[cifs]

Comment: the issue has been resolved for now I have tried to comment shared drive from _/etc/fstab_ and _umount_ it then remount it again.

Answer (score -1):

I’m on an android right now so your system might be a little different but in Termux, df does not accept any options at all.

df # works as expected

df [FILE] # works as expected

df [OPTION]…  [FILE]… # No such file or directory error

Comment: This actually does not explain the problem in the question at all.